# Battery replacement specifications

Tags: laptop, battery-life, battery

My battery is dead and I would like to replace but cant find the same exactly battery on the market.

```
Laptop: HP omen 15-dc1001nv

Battery: SR04XL
         15.4V --- 70.07Wh (Nom: 4550mAh)
```

[image]

I have found some `sr04xl` but specifications do not much (different `mAh`)
For example the following battery with these characteristics (`15.4V` but `3500mAh`):

[image]

Would the difference `3500mAh` with the current battery `4550mAh` not combatible?

How can I define 'same characteristics' on batteries so I know what I am searching for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

mAh is just battery capacity 3500 won't last as long as a 4500